# Lista de strings + .Split()

Tags: c#, .net, array, string, lista

O comando `string.Split()` separa uma *string* em um *array* do tipo `string[]`. Como usar o `string.Split()` para separar strings em uma *lista* `List < string>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pelo .NET não tem como porque não há métodos (ou sobrecargas do `Split()`) nele que devolvam o que você quer, a API foi feita para resultar em um *array* e só assim. Ou você faz um método próprio que faça isso, o que é quase certo que será pouco eficiente, ou você deve transformar o resultado em lista depois de obter o *array*.

[Para minha decepção isso é pouco eficiente](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,d2ac2c19c9cf1d44) (mas é mais que você fazer na mão). A situação é ridícula e vou tentar descobrir mais. Pode criar a lista assim:

Ou pode usar o método `.ToList()` do LINQ que acabará chamando o construtor acima e terá, em essência, a mesma eficiência e dará uma sintaxe um pouco mais confortável.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6".Split(',').ToList();
        var array = "1,2,3,4,5,6".Split(',');
        var lista2 = new List<string>(array);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iL27bs). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dKLyZR). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/SplitToList.cs).

Aparentemente os únicos meios de você resolver isso de forma otimizada seriam:

- Criar sua própria `string` (isso tem sérias implicações e não vai funcionar bem
- Criar sua própria lista (pode ser um pouco melhor, mas ainda gerará dificuldades em outros pontos de interação com a aplicação)
- Criar a lista com reflexão e colocar o *array* na lista de forma manual. Isso é possível porque `List` tem um *array* interno, mas tem que fazer certo e saber que se internamente a implementação de `List` mudar seu código não funcionará mais até fazer adaptação. Isso é improvável, mas pode acontecer.
- Pedir para a equipe do .NET criar um construtor que aceite um *array* sem fazer a cópia. Eu nem tentaria porque há bons motivos para fazer, mas motivos melhores para não fazer.

Comment: "Pelo .NET não tem como", como assim? Sei que não é escopo, mas aproveitando :P

Comment: A API do `Split()` não retorna um `List`, só *array*, então o que ele perguntou de separar em uma lista não tem como, aí tem as opções que eu disse para obter a lista.

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer que o método Split não possui um `overload` que te retorne uma List<T> por default.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o escopo do .NET, você quer dizer que o Linq não pertence ao .NET?

Comment: @WictorChaves melhorou agora? Vamos ver se alguém sabe algo, mas duvido que tenha um jeito melhor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353009/efficiency-of-list-creation-from-array

Answer (score 10):

O método `Split()` te retorna um array de `string`, para transformar em uma lista você teria que convertê-lo, para isso pode utilizar o método `.ToList();`:

```
string texto = "1;2;3;4;5";
List<string> listaString = texto.Split(';').ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Para usar este recurso é necessário importar o seguinte pacote, já que o `ToList` é um método do `Linq`

```
using System.Linq;
```

Basta colocar o método `ToList` depois do método `Split`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
listStrLineElements = line.Split(',').ToList();
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263695/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-to-a-liststring)

Answer (score 1):

Só para dar mais uma opção com Extension: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lst = "0,1,2,3,4,5".SplitList(',');
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<string> SplitList(this string str, char split)
    {
       return  str.Split(split).ToList();
    }
}
```